# Select max date for user having sum(worktime) < x

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Need help with query - I'm using both SQL Server and MySQL.

I have a table of working hours of users which looks like this:

```
USER  WORKTIME DATE
user1 08:00:00 2015-03-01
user1 08:00:00 2015-03-02
user1 08:00:00 2015-03-03
user2 08:30:00 2015-03-11
user2 10:00:00 2015-03-13
user3 05:00:00 2015-03-11
user3 05:00:00 2015-03-12
user3 05:00:00 2015-03-14
```

What I need is the last date for every user when sum of his worktime is less or equal x - for this example let's say it's 18 - PLUS sum of worktime up to that date - so my result should be:

```
USER  WORKTIME DATE
user1 16:00:00 2015-03-02
user2 08:30:00 2015-03-11
user3 15:00:00 2015-03-14
```

When using simple query like this:

```
select user, 
       sum(worktime), 
       max(date)
from worktime
group by user
having sum(worktime) <= 18
```

I get only users whose total of hours are <= 18, which for this example is user3.

I know how to do it with 2 separate queries and some excel functions, but was wondering if it's possible to do it within single statement.

Comment: In sql-server there windowing functions that would be A++ for this example... except for those comma seperated values. If it's at all possible, you should normalize those things so each worktime has it's own record.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? 

BTW forgot to mention - I've also ID in this table, so every record is unique. About commas - this is just example. Worktime is of hh:mm:ss format, which then gets converted before summing.

Comment: So what is that `8,5` then? If Worktime is stored as hh:mm:ss then please include that in your sample data. My concern is that 8 and 5 are seperate worktimes, occupying the same record. If that is the case, they should each have their own record, otherwise your queries will be a nightmare.

Comment: 08:30:00. I edited my post.

Comment: was afk for a bit. I didn't realize the 8,5 was the international deal. That still throws me off. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for both databases, then I would suggest a correlated subquery to get the cumulative amount of time.  Then you can get the value that you want:

```
select user, max(date)
from (select wk.*,
             (select sum(wk2.worktime)
              from worktime wk2
              where wk2.user = wk.user and
                    wk2.date <= wk.date
             ) cume_worktime
      from worktime wk
     ) t
where cume_worktime <= 18
group by user;
```

This is ANSI standard SQL and should work in both databases.

Answer (score 0):

Do a left join with the same table (haven't tested it, but should be something along these lines):

```
select u.user, sum(u.worktime), max(u.date),
sum(u1.worktime)
from worktime AS u LEFT JOIN worktime AS u1 ON u.user=u1.user WHERE u1.date<max(u.date)
group by u.user
having sum(u.worktime) <= 18
```